# Open Network Capture Not Showing HTTP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireshark

I'm doing a course that involves capturing traffic on an open network. I just happened to be in a hotel at the time, so figured it would be easy to see traffic, because the hotel had open wifi. So I captured some traffic on the network with airodump in monitor mode and opened it up in Wireshark and didn't see anything but management frames. So I connected to the network and ran a capture of the traffic through Wireshark and still wasn't seeing any of the http traffic I was generating with another device. Is there some other level of encryption that takes place on another layer even when on an open network that is preventing me from seeing http traffic? Or should this traffic be visible? I also tried again on an open network that I setup at home and got the same result. I was not able to see the http traffic I was generating with another device while connected to the network and viewing the traffic via Wireshark.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you actually generating `HTTP` or `HTTPS` traffic?  If you're adding a filter for just `http`, you will not see `HTTPS` traffic.  If you use the filter: `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name != ""` for example, and add a column for `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name` then you should see all the domains you are browsing to as modern browsers set the domain in clear text in the Server Name Indication (SNI) extension at least for now.

Comment: Yes I am definitely generating http traffic. I can see it all passing on the machine I am using to test the lab. So I don't think adding that filter for https will work unless I'm missing something. I was just under the impression seeing other clients traffic on  an open network was much easier than it's proving to be haha

Answer (score 1):

If by "open" you mean "no wireless encryption (no WPA2, WPA, or WEP)", and if your card really was in monitor mode, and tuned to the same channel as a nearby AP, and if the other device was associated to that nearby AP (the one on the channel that your monitor mode device was tuned to), then there are still a handful of possible reasons you couldn't see the unicast HTTP traffic the other device was sending:

1. You might have been in monitor mode, but not promiscuous mode. Some Wi-Fi cards differentiate. Monitor mode means you see 802.11-specific details, but promiscuous mode means you see unicast traffic that wasn't meant for you.
2. Your target client and the AP may both have supported fancier modulation schemes than your monitor mode device supported, so your monitor mode device couldn't detect/decode their traffic. For example, if your target client and the AP both supported 2x2 MIMO, but your capture device was just 1x1 ("SISO", non-MIMO), your capture device wouldn't be able to see anything transmitted using 2 MIMO spatial streams.
3. Your monitor mode capture device might not have been in a good location to successfully receive packets sent between your AP and target client. Have you ever been at one end of a long table in a noisy restaurant and been unable to hear the conversation at the other end? Kinda like that. Your AP and target client may have had enough signal strength to each other to use faster modulation schemes, but your monitor mode client wasn't in a place where it could receive either device's transmissions clearly enough to decode difficult modulations reliably.

Comment: Spiff,  Thanks for the detailed answer. I have tried a couple different setups. I am traveling again right now and looking at Wireshark on a Mac Pro. The "Promiscuous" mode in Wireshark is checked for the NIC in the MAC and I'm connected to hotel WiFi. But again, not seeing any unicast traffic other than my own. As far as Alfa cards go, I have used an AWUS036NH and AWUS036ACH. Not sure if you're familiar enough with those to tell if your first case might be the reason. The MIMO thing makes sense as well...any advice on how to reliably all traffic for clients on an open network? Thanks again

Comment: You lugged a Mac Pro into a hotel? What model? I seem to recall the "trash can" model had 3x3 802.11ac, but with compromised antennas. So I'm unsure if it would be a good capture system. A 15" MBP 2013 or later would be better (3x3 802.11ac w/decent antennas).

Comment: That first Alfa model you listed isn't MIMO, it's SISO (1x1:1), so it's a terrible choice for capture. The second model is 2x2:2 MIMO, which is okay, but 3x3:3 is better. I don't know of any cards that can capture everything, because I have seen 4x4:4 client cards that only do 80MHz wide channels, and cards that support 160MHz-wide channels but with only 2 spatial streams. And now 802.11ax (Wi-Fi 6) is entering the scene, and that's a new can of worms.

Comment: It's getting to the point that listening to all the traffic on a Wi-Fi network is like trying to listen to every conversation at a busy cocktail party. It's just not possible from a single listener.

Comment: Spiff, I have a MBP 2018 (15"). I used the Wireless Diagnostic sniffer on my MBP and its the same story. All I see is Management Frames. I think it may have to do with the Monitor vs. Promiscuous mode you mentioned. Like I don't think any of the cards I'm using are trying to see unicast traffic.

Comment: Just for my own clarification, it is POSSIBLE to see these HTTP frames on an Open (unencrypted, no WPA/WPA2/WEP) network correct? Would I even have to connect to the network to see the unicast traffic? Thanks again for the help man

Comment: 15" MBPs are great wireless sniffers, because they support 3 spatial streams and 80MHz wide channels. Very very few client products support more spatial streams or wider channels than that (although that's changing as 802.11ax rolls out). I use my 15" MBP with Wireshark to capture open Wi-Fi traffic all the time, including unicast traffic, HTTP traffic, etc. I've also used the built-in Wireless Diags sniffer feature to capture HTTP traffic, and I've used tcpdump to do it as well. No, you do not have to join the network, you just have to tune to the channel that has the traffic you want on it.